# Connect Pentaho to MS SQL Server (Native)

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I am very new in using PENTAHO. I need to connect this software to MS SQL Server (Native). I already try to connect it many time but every time I test the connection, failed.
This is the error message that occur every time I test the connection.

```
Error connecting to database [sutera] : 
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class
```

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.1.133, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.1.133, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:368)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:317)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:279)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:269)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:86)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2464)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:533)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:234)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:256)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:162)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:156)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:759)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.1.133, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:504)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:352)
... 122 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.1.133, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:104
         9)
at 
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
at                                          
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:478)
... 123 more
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I really need your help. TQ

Comment: To connect to SQL Server in native mode, Java must be able to find the sqlauth.dll file. I solved this problem by modifying the spoon.bat file and providing the path to the sqlauth.dll file there. I think there's a much better way to do that, but I haven't tried it yet. Are you sure the host and port are correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the host & port are correct. Can you show me how you solve this problem? I'm very new in using this software. I just learned it for about 3 days.

Answer (score 19):

**Integrated Security Setup**

To connect to database with integrated security, following steps should be done:

- Download Microsoft JDBC Drivers 4.2 on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
- Unzip the package in a temp directory
- Close Spoon
- Copy '<temp directory>\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\auth\x86\sqljdbc_auth.dll' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin' (32-bit)
- Copy '<temp directory>\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar' to '<Kettle installation folder>\data-integration\lib'
- Open Spoon
- Test connection in spoon
- Delete temp directory

If you upgrade Kettle, Java, JDBC Driver to a higher version, you have to repeat the above steps

Comment: Installing Java in a version independent folder prevents to copy the file for each java update

Comment: Works also with Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server 6 and 8, only folder structure is a little different. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I dont believe, 'sqljdbc_auth.dll' needs to go to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin'. I believe it needs to got to the folder of Pentaho, that is: '...\data-integration\libswt\win64'.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me to connect Pentaho PDI to a Microsoft SQL Server:

1. Download the official Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (v4.0) from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
2. It comes bundled with two jar files, copy the file "sqljdbc4.jar" into your path `data-integration\lib`.
3. Restart Pentaho and try the connection `MS SQL server(Native)` again.

Note: I used this method for Pentaho PDI (Kettle), but it should work for the rest of products of the suite.

Note2: Even if you are using windows you can download the ".tar.gz" file instead of the ".exe" because you are using it just for Pentaho.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my solution because none of the above match exactly. 
I got the sqljdbc_auth.dll as was suggested in this article and just put it into the 
data-integration\libswt\win64 directory and started Spoon. I was able to authenticate after that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether you have followed these steps or not.but what i want to mention ::

1>first add jdbc driver for ms sql server add in **tomcat->lib**.
**sqljdbc4.jar**

*find the below image*
[image]

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: I already follow like what you show. However, it still failed to connect. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Do I need to install tomcat in server too?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server's "Inregratedsecurity" authentication feature to work you must copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll to the BA server's "~\tomcat\bin" location and restart the BA server.

Hope this'll help!

Answer (score 1):

add "sqljdbc41.jar" to \Pentaho\java\bin
and "sqljdbc_auth" (Diff for 32-bit and 64-bit version) to \Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib

Answer (score 1):

Just wrestled with this on my Mac.

By default the "root" directory when you unzip the archive is `data-integration`. I moved it over to a directory called "Pentaho" -- it's a small thing, but not exactly clear -- you want the JDBC driver in the lib sub-directory off of whatever ROOT directory you are using for Pentaho.

I used the latest JDBC driver -- `sqljdbc42.jar` -- works just fine -- worked just fine with the `mariadb-java-client-2.1.0.jar` for `Aurora DB` on `AWS RDS`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this kept me busy for a nasty little while. This is what worked for me:

System info:

- win10
- PDI community edition Version 9.4
- SQL Server 2019
- Java install 1: jre1.8.0_361
- Java install 2: jdk1.8.0_361

Download:

- Driver bundle "sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar.gz"
  from source https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
  (over time the exact name will change. the url seems to stay the same)

Actions:

1. shut down pentaho/spoon
2. unpack file "sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar.gz". this gets you a folder with subfolders and various files in them.
3. copy this file:
   "sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll"
   to this location:
   "...\data-integration\libswt\win64"
4. copy this file:
   "sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
   to this location:
   "...\data-integration\lib"
5. start up spoon

I hope this does it for You..

Thanks to the other posters.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Bart VdA's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1854492/bart-vda) steps, then go to Pentaho, file, new, transformation. Go to the preview tab, select transformation, click connections, new connection. Enter the default sql server settings as shown in the image below.

[image]